# Where can I configure SonarLint to order results by line number in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I get the corrections list, but it restarts the line order results over and over again.
Can I sort it by line number ascending?
Obs: I have SonarQube installed.

[image: Result list example]

Answer (score 0):

Sonar's philosophy is about Clean as You Code, meaning you should not focus on resolving old issues but only on issues related to your current work. As a result, SonarLint does not provide any way of sorting issues but will sort them by the introduction date in your code to enforce this vision.